# Android gsutil tool not working

Tags: android, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to export ratings and reviews from my Android App.

I followed to gsutil [instructions](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) and I could install gsutil on my computer then I tried export my ratings like follow

```
gsutil cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_XXXXXX/reviews/reviews_com.tupbebekailesi.serkanoral.hamilelikrehberi_2013*/Users/olkunmustafa
```

Then I get error below

```
CommandException: Wrong number of arguments for "cp" command.
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [synopsis of the gsutil command](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#synopsis) is the following:

```
gsutil cp [OPTION]... src_url dst_url
```

Your option is `-r` and then you need to type the origin (`src_url`) and the destination (`dst_url`) of the data.

In this case, you have indicated your bucket as `src_url` but the `dst_url` is missing and that's why you receive an error indicating a wrong number of arguments.

Therefore, as [Brandom Yarbrough has pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25825800/3906217), you need to put a space between the bucket and your folder `/Users/olkunmustafa`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: each answer are also correct but your answer is more helpfully for  me . Thank you

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a space betweeen "2013*" and "/Users/olkunmustafa".

Answer (score 0):

gsutil allows one to copy data within the cloud.

**command :** gsutil cp source_path destination_path

**Solution:** give space between * and /Users/olkunmustafa